# Pro / Cons of using push vs pushNamed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Can anyone outline the pro/cons of `push` vs `pushNamed` in flutter?

Doing some research, the only thing I could find was [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3867) requesting the same thing.

This is as far as I understand it:

**push**

- Doesn't use strings so reduces chances of mistyping a route.
- Pass arguments as a parameter in its constructor

**pushNamed**

- Uses strings but these can be set up as constants and then referenced
- Pass arguments via creating an object and extracting from it

Which one should I be using? 
Which one is recommended?
Is it down to particular use cases/scenarios?

I can see that if you're passing a lot of information to a new screen then it would be easier to do this using an object, but I tend to see `push` used more often.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to release your app on the web, pushNamed() is preferred over push() for a few reasons.

### Navigation works as expected on web apps

If you design your routes to accept arguments from the URL path or as query parameters, you won't need to worry about weird things happening when you refresh the page. If you use push() to navigate, refreshing a web page will cause a number of issues since the arguments that were passed in are not persisted across refreshes.

### It's easier to navigate declaratively

Imperative routing (eg. the type of routing where you create a navigation stack by pushing and popping routes) is known to cause [issues with browser history](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99112). This is one of the reasons why Navigator 2.0 and newer routing libraries like [go_router](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html) focus on declarative routing (eg. the type of routing where you tell Flutter exactly what the navigation stack should look like). Named routes encourage you to lean towards declarative routing.

### Deep links just work

Since every route is named and pulls all of its required arguments from the URL path, you can generally deep link to content in your app without doing too much else.

See the official [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) for (a little) more information.